# tensorflow error on Rasbian Desktop

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5

I am trying to install tensorflow on my VMware machine running Rasbian Desktop.
I followed the exact procedure on the tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_raspbian#ValidateYourInstallation) and got it installed and run successfully on my Raspberry Pi 3, model B. But when I tried it on my VM, I ran into problem...
Here's my breakdown process when I tried to do that in the VMware environment.

```
sudo apt-get -y install libatlas-base-dev
```

and the system returned

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libatlas-base-dev is already the newest version (3.10.3-1+b1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

then

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

system returned

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (0.11.0)
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (1.10.0)
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: protobuf==3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (3.0.0)
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: numpy>=1.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (1.14.5)
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (0.29.0)
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from protobuf==3.0.0->tensorflow) (40.0.0)
```

When I tried to validate the installation with Python3 by simply importing the tensorflow library, it showed me this error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't know what I did wrong in the process. I hope someone could help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: And the pip3 install only gives me the 0.11 version of tensorflow, not the latest.